# Infinispan. Can I have multiple clusters/namespaces/groups inside single server instance?

Tags: caching, micronaut, infinispan

I want to connect to a single infinispan server instance from multiple environments grouping caches in namespaces/groups. Can be possible? I use micronaut cache with infinispan 13. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is no longer possible to use multiple cache containers (which would have given you this functionality).